# Is the application tag inside the AndroidManifest the good place to specify a theme?

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm looking at the best way to specify the Holo.Light theme for my entire application.
Is the  tag the best place to specify that theme?

My code looks like that :

```
...
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
                android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <activity
...
```

Comment: It's a very good place to set the theme since doing the same in an Application class doesn't work and doing it in every Activity is unnecessary if you don't intend to use different themes.
Also if you do it in the manifest the app will start with the correct theme without showing visual artifacts when you'd do the same in the Activities

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is according to this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

quote:
*android:theme
A reference to a style resource defining a default theme for all activities in the application. Individual activities can override the default by setting their own theme attributes. For more information, see the Styles and Themes developer guide.*

more info on themes:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

As noted above, its not necessary to add it to each activity, when you want your whole application to be in one style you just add it to the application tag.